# How does the Colossal Titan's shifter escape without being seen?

Tags: attack-on-titan

In episode 5, immediately after Eren misses his shot to the Colossal Titan and it reverts to human form, I looked from multiple angles but there were no humans.

However, given what we know later, one would expect to see

> Bertolt Hoover

but they are not visible in the scene. How were they able to escape in the time before Eren attached to the wall and looked down?

[image]

Comment: that video does not play :P

Comment: @ton.yeung your flash is missing :P

Comment: @Entei: it doesn't for me either. Perhaps it was accidentally uploaded as an image?

Comment: Read [this](http://anime.stackexchange.com/q/23553/6345) and [this](http://anime.stackexchange.com/a/10034/6345) from where we can conclude that an experienced titan shifter can shift fast between human and titan act like a normal human ,move, run and disguise

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As mentioned in [@mirroroftruth's comment](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/23809/how-does-the-colossal-titan-vanish#comment34220_23809), an experienced Titan Shifter can easily morph between both their forms quickly, meaning it wouldn't be difficult for Bertolt to swiftly escape the body of his Colossal Titan. Additionally, if he already had 3D Maneuver Gear equipped (like Annie does in episodes 20/21 of the anime, mentioned in [this question](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/10030/how-was-annie-leonhart-able-to-get-out-of-her-titans-form/10034#10034)), escaping the area quickly would not have been an issue. Given the scenario of episode 5, it's highly unlikely that he *didn't* have this gear on his person.

Also, don't forget that the Colossal Titan is emitting an intense amount of heat and steam:

> "It is also constantly releasing jets of steam from the surface of its body...

And this can be amplified as a defensive mechanism, seen in the attack on Wall Rose:

[image: Steam]

> "...he possesses a powerful defense mechanism that involves him releasing large amounts of extremely hot and pressurized steam from his body. The steam has enough force to deflect any cables shot from the 3DMG and burn away or repel close-range fighters."
>
> <sub>Both excerpts taken from [Bertolt Hoover](http://shingekinokyojin.wikia.com/wiki/Bertolt_Hoover) on the SnK wiki</sub>

With the disappearance of such a massive body, the amount of steam produced would create a very effective combination of a repellent and a makeshift smokescreen. This would have been ample for Bertolt to escape from the scene without being seen.

---

This is confirmed on page 22 of chapter 72 - in the bottom left panel, there is a picture of Bertolt escaping while near a damaged wall. His 3D Maneuver Gear is clearly visible and he's under the cover of steam.

[image: pic]

Comment: in latest chapter 72 around 22 23 there is answer , Bertolt escaped using 3D  gear

Comment: That's still is not possible. The only ways for him to escape was going straight down, grappling to wall, or him transforming back into Titan Form. Which all possibilities include him being seen in one way or another.

Comment: @mirroroftruth all that is well and good.. but it doesn't explain how the titan body disappeared in an instant.. no titan shifter should be able to simply make the body disappear in an instant right? or do i have my facts wrong?

Answer (score 1):

In chapter 96 of the manga

> It is showed that Reiner climbed up the wall in his titan form while bringing Bertholdt and Annie.